# Scalars on a one dimensional field with inner product and non orthogonal basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a linear vector space with inner product, if $T$ is a operator on $V$, how can i prove that $Dim(Im (T))=1$ iff exists $u, w \neq 0$ in $V$, such that $T(v)=<v,u>w$ for all $v \in V$.

my try:

if $Dim(Im (T))=1$ , then there is $w$ that generate the image. Then, for all $v$ in $V$

$T(v)=\alpha w$, for $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.

I know that would be direct if i assume a orthogonal basis of $V$ but, at principle I would like to prove it for an ordinary basis $\{v_{1},...,v_{n}\}$.

Acctually, I was trying to put $w=v_{1}$ and then let the others vector become a basis to the Kernel of $T$, but i get no results. How can i use the inner producto information with an ordinary basis??

Comment: One suggestion: show that the $\alpha$ such that $T(v) = \alpha w$ is unique for a given $v$. Call it $\alpha_v$. Then show the function $v \mapsto \alpha_v$ is a linear transformation from $V$ to the field. By the Riesz Representation Theorem, there must be some $u$ such that $\langle v, u \rangle = \alpha_v$ for all $v$.

Comment: This basically boils down to knowing that every linear map $f: V \to \mathbb{R}$ may be written as $f(v) = \langle v, u \rangle$ for some $u \in V$. Do you know this theorem?

Comment: @joppy, I don't remember, is not that the Riesz mentioned above?

Comment: If $V$ is finite dimensional, then it is not a hard theorem at all. If $V$ is for example an infinite dimensional Hilbert space, then the theorem holds when $T$ is a bounded linear operator, and this is called the Riesz representation theorem.